# "There are a number of reasons {why/that}..."

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, relative-pronouns

Should it be:

> There are a number of reasons **why** I don't like him.

Or

> There are a numbers of reasons **that** I don't like him.

?

Both sentences sound well but I am confused, are both correct? When to use *that or why* after "reason" in such sentences?

Comment: Both options are correct with little or no difference in meaning. Both are omissible too: "There are a number of reasons I don't like him".

Comment: @user178049 it means above-mentioned sentences would be correct, even if we don't add why/that

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would be:

> There are a number of reasons why I don't like him.